# How do I create a JSON object in C?

Tags: c, json

I currently have a string in C that I have coded like this:

```
#define MESSAGE_STRING "{\"deviceName\":string, \"Telemetry\":{\"voltage\":12,\"current\":0.12}}"
```

As I am sending it to a cloud service that processes it as a JSON message and receives this:
[image]

But I want to do this in an easier way as this could get a lot more complex when I am sending more complicated JSON messages. I was wondering if there was any easy way to create these JSON objects within C easier?
Cheers

Comment: Write a function to generate the string into a buffer using (multiple calls to) `snprintf`. Once you've done it by hand a few times, factor the boilerplate into some helper functions or simple api.

Comment: C does not provide any JSON support. You will need to look for some open source library. Take a look at [Jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [JSON-C](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/) Or look at the references at [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write your JSON in a text file, and replace every parameter with a %d, %f, %s placeholder.
Then read this file, and fill in the values with sprintf()
But pay attention to the order of your parameters.

**json.txt:**

```
{
    "device_name": "%s",
    "Telemetry": {
        "voltage": %d,
        "current": %f
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char json_format[4096];
    char message_string[4096];
    FILE* fp;

    // Read in json format
    fp = fopen("json.txt", "r");
    int len = fread(json_format, 1, 4096, fp);
    json_format[len] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    // Fill in parameters
    const char* device_name = "string";
    int         voltage = 12;
    float       current = 0.12;
    sprintf(message_string, json_format, device_name, voltage, current);

    printf("%s", message_string);
}
```

The code is only for understanding the concept.
It works, but don't use it, because it doesn't check for erorrs and the memory management is bad too.